# Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, oracle, node-oracledb

I have created an API and want to insert data into the oracle database. But I received an error message "Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number".I don't know what mistake I have made. Hope can help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

> [Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number] {
>       errorNum: 1036,
>       offset: 0
>     }

```
//post 
async function AddData(form){

     console.log(form);

     let Status = {
          status:_const.MSG_STATUS_ERROR,
          message:_const.MSG_STATUS_ERROR,
          info:null
     };


     let connection;
     let date = new Date();

     try{
          connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbconfig);

          const result = await connection.execute(
               `INSERT INTO EIS_PANTAURUM 
               (    
                    PAN_ZONRUMPUT,PAN_TAMRUMPUT,PAN_BULANPTAU,PAN_MASAPNTAU,
                    PAN_STATUSKOD,PAN_CATATANSS,PAN_SEBLUMPIC,PAN_SLEPASPIC,
                    PAN_SEMASAPIC,PAN_ENTRYOPER,PAN_ENTRYDATE,PAN_TIMESAMPM,
                    PAN_PUSINGANS,PAN_TAHUNRPUT
               )
               VALUES
               (    :zon,:taman,:bulan,:masa,
                    :status,:catatan,:sebelumPic,:selepasPic,
                    :semasaPic,:entryOperator:entryDate,:timeAMPM,
                    :pusingan,:tahun
               )`,{zon:form.zon,taman:form.taman,bulan:form.bulan,masa:form.masa
                    ,status:form.status,catatan:form.catatan,sebelumPic:"Empty.jpg",selepasPic:"Empty.jpg"
                    ,semasaPic:"Empty.jpg",entryOperator:form.entryOperator,entryDate:date,timeAMPM:form.timeAMPM
                    ,pusingan:form.pusingan,tahun:form.tahun}
          );

          Status.status = _const.MSG_STATUS_SUCCESS;
          Status.message = _const.MSG_STATUS_SUCCESS;
          Status.info = result.rowsAffected;     


     }catch(err){
          console.error(err);
          Status.message = err;
          return Status;

     }finally{
          if(connection){
               try{
                    await connection.close();
               }catch(err){
                    console.error(err);
                    Status.message = err;
                    return Status;
               }
          }
     }

     return Status;

}

router.post('/api/AddData/:zon/:syarikat/:alamat_syarikat/'+
          ':nama_penyelia/:taman/:bulan/:tahun/:masa/:timeAMPM/:pusingan/:status/:catatan/:state/'+
          ':entryOperator',(req,res) =>{

     AddData(req.params).then(function(value){
          console.log(value);
          res.send(value);
     })`enter code here`
})
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your stack trace? It will have a line number. Briefly reading your code the date in `date = new Date();` is also undefined.

Comment: @BlueWater86 I added line number and the date also show value: 2020-01-15T03:31:08.486Z

Comment: That's not the line number.

Comment: You still haven't declared your 'date' variable.

Comment: already added   'let date = new date();' but still received the same error msg.

Comment: Am totally new, but [from example](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/insert1.js) I see, For setting bind variables using name, the syntax is like `{zon: {value : form.zon}....`

Comment: I'm not familiar with node-oracledb, but the problem could be `selepasPic:"Empty.jpg"`. In straight-up Oracle, the double quotes make the value an object *name*. Single quotes make it an object *value*. Try `selepasPic:'Empty.jpg'` instead.

Comment: There is a typo in ":entryOperator:entryDate" in the VALUES SQL clause,  You are missing a comma.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thank you sir!.able to solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a comma missing in

```
:entryOperator:entryDate
```

It has to be the following here

```
:entryOperator,:entryDate
```

I'd recommend you to use spaces after each comma. Such a habit helps you to avoid errors like that one